# How to find the linear matrix of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

---

[image]

I know the answer is [image]. But what is the intuition behind the answer?

Comment: What do you know about linear transformations and matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Given a orthonormal basis $\{\vec e_i\}$, ($1\le i\le n$) and a linear transformation that transform 
$$ \vec e_1\rightarrow \vec v_1,\quad\vec e_2\rightarrow \vec v_2;\quad \vec e_3\rightarrow \vec v_3; \quad \cdots \vec e_n\rightarrow \vec v_n $$ then $ \vec v_1$ is the first column of the matrix that represent such transformation, $ \vec v_2$ is he second column, $ \vec v_3$ is the third and so on. I.e: the matrix is: $M=[\vec v_1,\vec v_2, \cdots \vec v_n]$.

This is a consequence of the fact that any vector is a linear combination af the basis vectors and the transformation is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you do $M*e_1$ then you should end up with $v_1$ and the same for $e_2$ and $v_2$.

So for $M*e_1 = (1*M_{11}+0*M_{12},1*M_{21}+0*M_{22}) = (M_{11},M_{21}) = v_1 = (-2, 3)$